# Pandas column returning nonetype despite having values for all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, nonetype

I have downloaded a dataset using the code and output below:

```
    def aroon(symbol):
        aroon =  TechIndicators(key='',output_format='pandas')
        data, meta_data = aroon.get_aroon(symbol = symbol, interval = 'daily')
        modifiedfp = pandas.DataFrame(data)
        modifiedfp = modifiedfp.reset_index()
        modifiedfp
        print modifiedfp

      x = aroon('msft')
```

and output:

```
          date  Aroon Down  Aroon Up
    0 2020-04-07        45.0     100.0
    1 2020-04-08        40.0      95.0
    2 2020-04-09        35.0      90.0
    3 2020-04-13        30.0      85.0
    4 2020-04-14        25.0     100.0
    5 2020-04-15        20.0      95.0
    6 2020-04-16        15.0     100.0
    7 2020-04-17        10.0     100.0
    8 2020-04-20         5.0      95.0
    9 2020-04-21         0.0      90.0

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

The data table comes out fine, but when I try to isolate a column with the following, I receive this error:

```
    y = x['Aroon Down']

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/davidgaballa/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.3/scratches/scratch_7.py", 
    line 37, in <module>
    y = x['Aroon Down']
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Ultimately, I want to append one of these columns to another dataframe, but I ran into this same problem when I tried and have been working backwards to isolate the issue. It appears to me that all rows have a value so I'm not sure why I'm encountering this problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually returning anything in your `aroon` function. Modify it as so:

```
def aroon(symbol):
        aroon =  TechIndicators(key='',output_format='pandas')
        data, meta_data = aroon.get_aroon(symbol = symbol, interval = 'daily')
        modifiedfp = pandas.DataFrame(data)
        modifiedfp = modifiedfp.reset_index()
        print modifiedfp
        return modifiedfp
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ralvi. That was of course exactly right. I didn't realize that something separate from "print" was required to save it to memory, but it seems intuitive now.

Comment: Ralvi, when I do 
    print modifiedfp
    return modifiedfp

I get the data table, but when I reverse it to : 

    return modifiedfp
    print modifiedfp
   
I get nothing. Would you mind explaining how it works in the background?

Comment: It depeneds on what you mean with 'you get nothing'. If it's not printing anything, it happens because when the `return` statement is executed the function terminates, thus the `print` statement is never hit. You call your dataframe `x` so if you do `print(x)` it should print correctly your dataframe.